# can't find referenced method 'com.google.firebase.tasks.Task setValue(java.lang.Object,java.lang.Object)'

Tags: java, android

I am trying to build apk for my app but i keep receiving this error. I have deleted the previous sections i was using geofire but unfortunately i keep getting the same error. what might be the problem?

```
 Warning:com.firebase.geofire.GeoFire: can't find referenced method 'com.google.firebase.tasks.Task setValue(java.lang.Object,java.lang.Object)' in program class com.google.firebase.database.DatabaseReference
```

Answer (score 4):

In my case the problem was in using *Proguard* to create release APK (which removed some classes used by *geofire*).

The solution was to tell *Proguard* to keep everything in `com.firebase` package:

```
-dontwarn com.firebase.**
-keep class com.firebase.** { *; }
-keep interface com.firebase.** { *; }
```